# QGIS run python script upon print composer export

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, export, print-composer, events

I'm looking for a way to execute a python script upon exporting a print composer. Specifically, I want it to run once for each page exported. (logging some data and possibly updating a database).

So far I've created a custom expression that writes a log to a file and returns an empty string. I created an off-page label that runs the expression.

The problem is, this runs every time the page refreshes so it's running a bunch just paging through the atlas.

Trying to get it to run only on export, I put it in the 'export filename' field but that too runs every time the page refreshes.

Is there some way I can either force it to only run on export, or in the python code detect if the page is being exported before running?

edit:
here's the test code I'm running so far:

```
def logTest(logitem):
    global logFileName
    f = open(logFileName, 'a')
    f.write("{}\n".format(logitem))
    f.close()

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Territory')
def postData(postItem, feature, parent):
    logTest(str(postItem))
    return u''
```

and my expression to test it is simply:

```
postData("id")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. Created a feature request here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15726

Comment: Could you make a workaround based on catching the QgsComposerMap.preparedForAtlas() signal?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't know how to do that but I will research.

Comment: @JesseMcMillan Please post the feature request as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently possible. Feature request here:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15726